# Лучший метод вспомнить свой код двухмесячной давности

Tags: java

Уезжал отдыхать на дачу на месяц и еще на месяц оказался втянут в дела не связанные с проектом. В итоге вернувшись решил дописывать. Текущий объем около 10 000 строк. Какого же было мое удивление когда я обнаружил внутри огромные без причины закомментированные куски(точнее причина конечно была но я не могу ее вспомнить при этом объяснение в коде отсутствует), десятки "poorly named variables" (убирание хотя бы одной из которых вызывает по 50 ошибок), недописанные функции непонятного назначения(они компилируются, но видимо не делают то что нужно), объявления классов экземпляры которых нигде не создаются(возможно они понадобятся в будущем?), `TODO` листы по которым невозможно определить реализовано ли то о чем они говорят в коде, комментарии противоречащие друг другу. При попытке запуска появляется сообщение о `Null Pointer Exception` в строке номер 2456. Дело осложняется еще и тем, что я не помню что из запланированного может и не может выполнить текущая версия кода. Смотрю на все это как баран на новые ворота и не знаю что делать? Пока ничего лучше перечитывания и попыток вспомнить зачем нужна та или иная часть, я не придумал.

Есть ли еще какие-нибудь годные методы, чтобы облегчить такую ситуацию?

P.S. Никогда не прерывайтесь, работайте над проектом непрерывно. Горькая правда которую я понял на собственном опыте.

Comment: лучший способ вспомнить - прочесть его.

Comment: ну и в чем проблема? в любом случае код писался по ТЗ, даже если оно было только у вас в голове. почитайте ТЗ/сформулируйте на бумаге. потом возвращайтесь к коду. ТЗ поможет вспомнить что к чему

часто сталкивался с подобным когда начинал писать маленький проэкт для себя а в следующий раз когда появлялось время он ставал для меня неподьемным, - абсолютно отшибало что к чему. для себя решил писать ТЗ/RS даже для подобных поделок

Comment: Надо сделать заново, по другому, лучше.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

У меня будут следующие советы:

1. Даже если я пишу один, то я все равно выкладываю исходники под VCS - хотя бы на локальном репозитории. По истории транзакций всегда проще понять где и что.
2. Стараюсь пользоваться аннотацией @todo
3. Всегда стараюсь следовать некой [naming convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_conventions_(programming))
4. Если не могу вспомнить начинаю с кодирования мелкого, малозначащего куска, по ходу пьесы все равно вспоминаю кто есть who

**P.S.** Не прерываться - увы невозможно.

Comment: комментарии решают, главное не ленится их писать, даже на какбы очевидном коде

Comment: главное писать комменты вида зачем делается, а не что делается

Comment: кстати, встречал много раз обфускацию и полное отсутствие комментариев в случае когда изначальный программер считает себя незаменимым, поддержка кода превращается в ад, но программер незаменимым не становится. так что комментарии и naming convention плюсую неистово.

Comment: полностью согласен. больше всего спасают тудушки, - когда занимаюсь реализацией одного метода/класса и приходит идея связанная совсем с другими. то сразу же пишу туду для каждой идеи на месте. потом когда закончу можно к ним вернутся и решить что нужно/важно а что нет

Comment: отлично сказано. Жаль, нельзя на хэшкоде добавить коментарии в мэмориз( Лучший способ быстро вспомнить код - прочитать его, но при этом код должен быть чистым

Answer (score 9):

Если пару месяцев назад Вы написали 10000 строк (кстати, за какое время ?) и не можете понять, что они делают, то возможны 2 варианта.

1. Задача Вас не трогает. Выбросьте ее вместе с кодом.
2. Задачу Вы хорошо помните и она интересна. Значит код ужасен. Напишите его заново.

Если задача  понятна, то хороший код нормально читается, он неким образом самоочевиден, соответствует логике задачи.

Достаточно подробные комментарии к функциям (с пояснением *для чего она нужна*), естественно не помешают (код можно внимательно не читать), но только если комментарии актуальные. Если комментарии коду не соответствуют, то это беда.

Если задачу все-таки сделать надо, то для начала попробуйте описать ее русским языком (в файле !!!) на двух-трех уровнях детализации. Потом по этому описанию (оно станет основой комментариев) пишите код. Если возможно разбивайте его на независимые самодостаточные куски, которые можно тестировать раздельно. К тестовым данным (или описанию тестовых действий для интерактива) обязательно пишите пояснения и *обязательно* - ожидаемый результат. Кстати, описание тестовых данных делайте *вместе* с кодом. Первый вариант данных сделайте до того, как напишите последнюю функцию.

При нормальном стечении обстоятельств, учитывая, что это уже второй заход, IMHO за пару месяцев Вы напишите тысяч 5 строк программы - значительно улучшенный аналог нынешних 10К строк.

Answer (score 7):

Ответ будет банален - пишите понятный код, давайте понятные имена переменным, классам, методам, делайте методы короткими.
Для облегчения запоминания что делали стоит использовать систему контроля версий (svn, git итп), тогда можно будет по комментариям к коммитам и истории логов восстановить что делали и на чем остановились.

Comment: Что самое забавное, все эти нудные рекомендации работают, каждое слово. Просто иногда их надо прочувствовать на собственной шкуре. И тогда оказывается: "блин! А люди-то не дураки!".
Для меня когда-то было, например, открытием, что хороший код (т.е. делающий большую и сложную работу) может выглядеть просто. Для этого мне должен был попасть в руки чужой хороший код :) .
+ думайте в процессе "а зачем я вот это делаю?", "а это я пойму, если вернусь к коду через полгода?"

Answer (score 4):

**Никогда не прерывайтесь** - это суровый и непрактичный совет =) Было бы качество кода лучше, думаю, у вас таких идей бы не возникло.

По теме - вместо того, чтобы читать код, воспользуйтесь отладчиком и смотрите на code flow - кто какие методы вызывает, что меняется в методах, как это отражается на поведении. Возьмите N стандартных задач для приложения и пройдитесь по ним с дебаггером в руках.

---

Можете также глянуть в сторону UML диаграмм и других архитектурных способов визуализации Code Dependencies - возможно, если "нарисовать код", то станет понятнее.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к уже существующим ответам: прочитайте книгу Роберта Мартина «Чистый код».

Answer (score 2):

Я лично никогда не ленюсь писать тонны "детсадовских" комментариев с расжевыванием для "самого себя", так как на практике мне часто приходится лазить для переделки и добавления новых фич в свой собственный код многих разных проектов. Даже если некий метод в коде называется `checkWhetherNumberBelongsToShortCodesList`. На практике я убедился, что даже тогда, когда приходит идея игнорировать мысль вставить комментарий в месте, совсем уж кажущемся банальными, не стоит отказываться от его вставки - через пару месяцев мне приходилось вспоминать даже не то, что именно делает этот кусок кода, но более того - приходилось вспоминать реализацию проекта вообще.

Comment: Только тут важно еще не лениться править эти комментарии вместе с исправлениями кода.

Answer (score 1):

Уже практически всё ответили, но это делу не поможет, а говорит о том, как надо было...

Да, есть рекомендации, что делать, чтобы больше не наступать на эти грабли:

1. Контроль версий. Не следует пренебрегать комментарием к комиту и не стоит комитить нерабочий/недоделанный код. Тогда всегда можно будет восстановить последнюю или любую другую рабочую версию.
2. Именование переменных и методов должно соответствовать тому, что происходит в программе. Не стоит делать крупные классы и методы, тогда изменения в любом из модулей будет более изолированными.
3. Желательно держать в голове архитектуру программы, хотя бы основное.
4. Используйте автоматическое тестирование. Тогда сразу будет ясно, что в программе работает, а что нет.

Что делать, когда уже случилось то, что вы описали... Придётся долго и муторно разбираться. Советую начать именно с тестов. Ведь что должна уметь программа и для чего она нужна вы вряд-ли забыли... Значит проверяйте, что работает, что нет, исправляйте ошибки.